# How to convert string to array with ranges JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Consider the following string: `7, 20, 22, 30–32, 33, 36–40, 46`

I developed some code that will automatically parse said string into an array with the given ranges as follows.

*Note: A typical use-case for this would be - to search for selected pages within a pdf with 100's of pages*

```js
var number_string = "7, 20, 22, 30–32, 33, 36–40, 46".toString().replace(/–/gi, '-').replace(/ /gi, '').split(',');
var new_arr = [];

$.each(number_string, function(index, value) {
  if (value.match(/-/gi)) {
    var range_arr = value.split('-');
    var sub_arr = range(range_arr[0], range_arr[1]);
    $.each(sub_arr, function(sub_index, sub_value) {
      new_arr.push(parseInt(sub_value, 10));
    });
  } else {
    new_arr.push(parseInt(value, 10));
  }
});

console.log(new_arr);

function range(lowEnd, highEnd) {
  var arr = [],
    c = highEnd - lowEnd + 1;
  while (c--) {
    arr[c] = highEnd--
  }
  return arr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Was there a more streamlined non jQuery method that could have been leveraged here that is also, simple, light weight and easy to read?  Please no ES6 stuff as that is Greek to me.

Note: The `ToInt` function is just a function that returns a valid number or 0.

Comment: I see you are using only `each` function form jQuery. You could use `for of` instead.

Comment: So, yeah, `ToInt` ... hu ha Any reason for not likeing `parseInt(val, 10)`?

Comment: If ES6 is Greek, jQuery is Pig Latin.

Comment: First, as this is working code that you want to improve you should ask this question over at [codereview.se] (they're about improving code, we're about producing creating working code). Second: If "*ES6 stuff...is Greek to [you]*" think of that as an opportunity, and reason, to learn ES6 (ECMAScript seems to be running on annual updates currently, depending on browser implementation; it's not going to get easier to learn if you put it off).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan When I started this job over a year ago I thought the same thing (it's not my code).  Over time however, I've come to be enlightened (or lazier) `ToInt()` is that much easier to write given that you know what to expect from it.

Comment: Incidentally, why not simply use `String.prototype.match(/.../).map()` for example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cbra7mqy/

Comment: @DavidThomas That would not properly include ranges, which I think are desired - it works for OP's input, but for eg `39-41`, it would only result in `39, 41` rather than 39, 40, 41`

Comment: @Certain: given the question seems to be "this code works, how can it be improved" I wrote that suggestion to produce the same end-result as is produced in the question. Given that we're both - explicitly - making assumptions, the OP needs to clarify.

Comment: David your example there is incredible.  Can it that short without the ES6 stuff?  It's not so much that ES6 is Greek, but I have no desire to learn something that is not robust as jQuery.  jQuery works everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`jQuery.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method acts like a flat map (returned sub arrays are flattend). In the map's callback function, use [`String.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) to check if there's a dash. If not convert to number with the `+` operator and return. If there's a dash, split, use a for loop to convert the min and max to an array, and return the array.

```js
function convert(str) {
  var arr = jQuery.map(str.split(', '), function(s) {
    if(s.search('–') === -1) return +s;
    
    var minmax = s.split('–');
    var range = [];
    
    for(var i = +minmax[0]; i <= +minmax[1]; i++) range.push(i);
    
    return range;
  });
  
  return arr;
}

var number_string = "7, 20, 22, 30–32, 33, 36–40, 46";

var result = convert(number_string);
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Using ESNext I would use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of `jQuery.map()`, with [`String.inclues()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to detect the dash, and [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to generate the sub array.

```js
const convert = (str) => 
  str.split(', ')
    .flatMap(s => {
      if(!s.includes('–')) return +s;
      
      const [min, max] = s.split('–');
      
      return Array.from({ length: max - min + 1 }, (_, n) => n + +min);
    });

var number_string = "7, 20, 22, 30–32, 33, 36–40, 46";

var result = convert(number_string, '–');
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm a stickler for browser compliancy, please kindly get rid of the indexOf and use `jQuery.inArray()`

Comment: jQuery.inArray won't work here because I was using String.indexOf. Convert to String.search.

Comment: `.search()` is only IE12.  If it's only string searching, can't we just use `.match()` or `.test()` with a regex or something.  This is definitely the answer I was looking for

Comment: our platform supports IE9

Comment: Search is supported by IE6 and above.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `.reduce`. First split the initial string by commas. If the string being iterated over doesn't have `-`, then just push the number to the accumulator; otherwise, split by `-` to get a `low` and `high` number, then use a `for` loop to push all numbers from `low` to `high` to the accumulator:

```js
const ToInt = Number;

const numArr = "7, 20, 22, 30–32, 33, 36–40, 46".split(', ');
const result = numArr.reduce((a, str) => {
  if (!str.includes('–')) {
    a.push(ToInt(str));
    return a;
  }
  const [low, high] = str.split('–');
  for (let i = Number(low); i <= high; i++) {
    a.push(i);
  }
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

If for some reason you don't want to use ES6, you can transform it to ES5 with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/):

```js
"use strict";

function _slicedToArray(arr, i) {
  return (
    _arrayWithHoles(arr) || _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) || _nonIterableRest()
  );
}

function _nonIterableRest() {
  throw new TypeError("Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance");
}

function _iterableToArrayLimit(arr, i) {
  var _arr = [];
  var _n = true;
  var _d = false;
  var _e = undefined;
  try {
    for (
      var _i = arr[Symbol.iterator](), _s;
      !(_n = (_s = _i.next()).done);
      _n = true
    ) {
      _arr.push(_s.value);
      if (i && _arr.length === i) break;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    _d = true;
    _e = err;
  } finally {
    try {
      if (!_n && _i["return"] != null) _i["return"]();
    } finally {
      if (_d) throw _e;
    }
  }
  return _arr;
}

function _arrayWithHoles(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) return arr;
}

var ToInt = Number;
var numArr = "7, 20, 22, 30–32, 33, 36–40, 46".split(", ");
var result = numArr.reduce(function(a, str) {
  if (str.indexOf("–") === -1) {
    a.push(ToInt(str));
    return a;
  }

  var _str$split = str.split("–"),
    _str$split2 = _slicedToArray(_str$split, 2),
    low = _str$split2[0],
    high = _str$split2[1];

  for (var i = Number(low); i <= high; i++) {
    a.push(i);
  }

  return a;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

(but the ES6 version is more concise and probably a *lot* easier to read and understand)

Comment: Your `.reduce()` callback can be shorter. `(a, str) => {
      a.push(...str.split('–').map(ToInt));
      return a;
    };` Or with `.concat()` to make it even shorter.

Comment: It's my fault for not mentioning it but it needs to be super browser compliant (reduce is not) if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @ziggywiggy While that would work for the *exact* input in the question, it wouldn't work for *ranges*. I'm assuming that, eg `47-49`, he wants 47, 48, and 49 to be pushed. Just splitting on `-` and pushing both would only push `47` and `49`.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon `Array.prototype.reduce` is from [ES 5.1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). If your users are running browsers which don't even support ES5, I'd consider that to be a problem with the users, not with your script :P

Comment: Oh yes, very true. Though you could eliminate the first `if` statement, since you'll always get an array back with at least one member. EDIT: If you fill in a default value for the `high`.

Comment: @ziggywiggy It's a possibility, but I think the code is more readable where the separate branches (either a `-` in the string, or not) are completely separate

Comment: Readability is truly a benefit too

Comment: @CertainPerformance `const ToInt = Number` ... Certainly not. :) `1.1` *is* a Number but, dear, not an *integer*. Use rather `ToInt = parseInt` ... or better throw that nonsense away and go chocolatishly vanilla

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan OP was using `ToInt` in his original code for some reason, its definition wasn't included in the code and I wasn't sure what exactly it was for, so I just left its logic alone for when a standalone number was encountered. The function, whatever it does, is already defined in the actual code, so I just set it to `Number` for a runnable snippet

Comment: @CertainPerformance Certainly. Just saying for some future fellas copying your answer and trustworthingly believing that `ToInt` does really what  says: `Number` :\

Answer (score 0):

I have my own implementation for this purpose
parseStringRange accepts strings like '1,2,3' and '1,2,3-5,6,7', also removes invalid chars (not numbers or , or -) and return one array with all numbers.

the function also returns the numbers ordered and removes duplicates, the user also can input unordered numbers even in range, '1-5' and '5-1' will return same output.

```
const parseStringRange = (range = '') =>
`${range}`
    ?.replace(/[^0-9,-]/g, '') //remove invalid chars
    ?.split(',') //convert 1,2 to [1, 2]
    ?.flatMap(s => { //convert 1-3 to [1,2,3]
        if (!s.includes('-')) return [s]

        const [min, max] = s.split('-').map(e => Number(e))

        if (min > max) var i = -1
        else var i = 1

        const r = []

        for (let p = min; p != max; p += i)
            r.push(p)

        r.push(max)

        return r;
    })
    ?.map(e => Number(e)) //convert all string numbers to number
    ?.reduce((t, e, i, a) => {
        if (!t)
            t = [... new Set(a)]
        return t
    }, null) //remove duplicates
    ?.sort((a, b) => a - b) //sort numbers, smallest first
```